# deaktivate/disable apache2 .htaccess authentication per directory/location env/setenv/setenvif

Tags: authentication, .htaccess, directory, location, apache2

To find out how to controll the Apache2 .htaccess authentication forced me hours to search a solution which a ton of solutions that didn't work
or was complicated as hell.

All you need:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/mydir/?" allow
AuthUserFile /your/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
Require env allow
```

Comment: If you want to answer your own question then post a question AND an answer (and "accept" it), otherwise readers won't find it. However, this solution will not work if you have a front-controller pattern in `.htaccess` (like WordPress or most CMS etc.) If you are on Apache 2.4 then you can use an Apache `<If>` expression, which is perhaps easier to "read" for some. Note that your regex `^/mydir/?` is the same as `^/mydir`, you probably meant `^/mydir($|/)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out how to controll the Apache2 .htaccess authentication forced me hours to search a solution which a ton of solutions that didn't work or was complicated as hell.

See Comment of MrWhite, your can try:

```html
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/mydir/?" allow
AuthUserFile /your/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
Require env allow
```